# Getting font and heading tags inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div which has sub tags. I want to get all heading and font tag style

```
<div id="headline">
<h2 style="text-align: center;">
<font color="#33ffcc" style="font-weight: normal;" size="5">Expansion Pack</font></h2>
</div>
```

How can i get heading style font color, style and size. heading can be h1, h2, h3 etc and font tag can be like

```
  <font style="font-weight: normal;" size="5">Expansion Pack</font>
  <font style="font-weight: normal;">Expansion Pack</font>
```

i tried using jquery

```
var text_align = $('#headline').css('text-align');
```

but i am getting `start` as the result.

Can anyone help me in this issue.

Comment: $('#headline h2').css('text-align')

Comment: thanks but h2 can be h1 ,h4, h5 how to detect which heading is created because these tags are generated dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
alert('Header Tag:  '+$('#headline :header').prop('tagName'));
alert('Header Tag text-align: '+$('#headline :header').css('text-align'));
alert('FONT Tag font-weight:  '+$('#headline :header font').css('font-weight'));
alert('FONT Tag font-size:  '+$('#headline :header font').css('font-size'));
alert('FONT Tag color:  '+$('#headline :header font').css('color'));
alert('FONT Tag attr size: '+$('#headline :header font').attr('size'));
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/6ugz3swL/3/)

Comment: and how to get font values inside the header

Comment: using selectors directly font-weight is returning 400 and what about font size and color?

Comment: you have 1 font element or more than one??

Comment: just one font tag but some font tags have color and size values and some dont.